# Stop iframe check script from switching sources when the first source is found

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have 2 hosts, 1 is a plain hosting and the other is a gameserver. I need to display a page on the hosting that exists on the gameserver if it's available. I'm currently running this code to change the iframe source when the page is unavailable to a another page on the hosting.

The issue I'm facing is that when the gameserver is online and the iframe fetches the source it still changes to the other page ping2.php while I want it to remain on the gameserver page ofcourse. I believe there is a stop missing but I'm a massive noob when it comes to scripts.

```js
<script>
function setIframeSrc() {
  var PingBoxWindow = document.getElementById('PingBoxWindow');
  var iframeLoadTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      window.stop();
  }, 4000);
  PingBoxWindow.src = "localofflinepage.php";
  PingBoxWindow.onload = function() {
      clearTimeout(iframeLoadTimeout); 
  }
}

window.onload = setIframeSrc;
</script>

<div id="block">
<iframe id="PingBoxWindow" name="PingBoxWindow" width="396" height="180" src="somegameserverurl/stats.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" scrolling="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the src regardless of the iframe load, you need to connect the two things together, in other words, flag the load success if it happens (which you are doing), but only change the src if the flag isn't set by the end of timeout. or simply by changing one line in your answer, which is moving the src changing line to the inside of the timeout.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script>
    function setIframeSrc() {
      var PingBoxWindow = document.getElementById('PingBoxWindow');
      var iframeLoadTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.stop();
        PingBoxWindow.src = "http://www.randomwebsite.com/";
      }, 4000);

      PingBoxWindow.onload = function() {
        clearTimeout(iframeLoadTimeout);
      }
    }

    window.onload = setIframeSrc;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe id="PingBoxWindow" src="http://www.theuselessweb.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now the page actually shows the gameserver file for 4 seconds then changes it back to the localofflinepage.php. We're getting close here but not perfect yet. Thanks though!

Comment: Tested, with the gameserver on it now stays on the gameserver stat page. But, with the gameserver turned off it no longer redirects to the localofflinepage.php. This is exactly what I've been experiencing with all scripts, either one or the other doesn't work. Thanks a ton for your time though.

Comment: i replaced the snippet with the whole html page i am testing with, and it's working on my device, please copy to a separate file and check (you can replace the src of the iframe with a wrong url to check the case of failure). if it works, compare it with your code

Comment: Ok I've added the script to my page http://www.pwutopia.ml/index.html and the registration is on. As you can see the script shows the online image for registration then switches back to the local offline page after 4 seconds while it should stay on the online page.